# Есть ли более менее адекватная онлайн система для проверки отображения сайта в разных браузерах?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, тестирование

Может, кто сталкивался с вопросом проверки отображения веб-сайта в различных браузерах и на разных операционных системах? Я много гуглил на эту тему. Есть такие системы. Но что-то они не очень-то хорошо делают свою работу. Поделитесь знаниями на эту тему. К каким онлайн-сервисам стоит присмотреться?

P.S.

Желательно чтобы у сервиса была возможность что-то типа пакетной обработки. Например, задаешь URL, а в ответ тебе серия скриншотов в разных системах и браузеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например сайт http://browsershots.org, есть возможность бесплатного использование с ограничениями.